# What are the best items/blocks to scan with the Thaumometer at the start?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I am wondering what are the best items/blocks one should scan at the beginning of a newly generated world to gain access to all Compound Aspects without the need to use a Research Table to discover them or needing to travel very far from where one starts (exceptions can be those found only in certain biomes, i.e. Snow).

This is for Thaumcraft 4 with no add-ons (so only Compound Aspects which are with Thaumcraft 4). Will also appreciate an order in which to can them as some block/items you can scan until you gain a certain Aspect.

Comment: I remember it was all the basic blocks\items. leaves, seeds, wood blocks, certain plants\crops, ect. sticks, stuff like that.

Comment: This post has a guide, but it's not perfectly research-free: https://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/thaumcraft-4-a-quick-way-to-discover-all-aspects-updated-for-4-2.33605/